# Which is better and secure method of writing PDO statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ok so I am in a confusion here. I have seen multiple queries like these.

Query 1

```
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE user = :user";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt);
$stmt-> bindValue(':user', $user);
$stmt-> execute();
```

Query 2

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE user = :user");
$stmt-> execute(['user' => $user]);
```

So, I want to know which of the above queries are most efficient and preferred while coding? Or is there any other better way than these to code in PDO?

Comment: removed 3rd....

Comment: There is no difference. Use whatever you like

Comment: Its your choice but in your 1st query u can save space to make a `SELECT` statement in `$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE user = :user");`

Comment: not using `bindValue` or `bindParam` will cause any difference? I mean risk of any SQL injection attacks or something in Query 2 ?

Comment: No, you are safe in both ways `$stmt->execute(array(":user"=>$user));`

Comment: You can use any of the way, both are secure...

Comment: No, they are identical, the array in execute is using bindParam internally, hence it works exactly the same, it's just cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not `bindParam`/`bindValue` that makes your query safe but `:user` thing that is called parameter or placeholder. As long as you have all variables in your query substituted with parameters, your query is 100% safe.

So you can tell that the second option is as safe as the fiirst one, though being more concise. Personally, I'd prefer positional placeholders that makes even more concise code:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE user = ?");
$stmt-> execute([$user]);
```

but all there variants are equally safe and only a matter of taste.